# Problems with rotating line around certain pivot

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, wpf-controls, line

I'm trying to build simple application which is rotating robotic arm around certain pivot. But my outcome is really strange. What can i do to change it to give proper values? 
I mean now it's floating around some weird point that i cannot recognise, but i already gave the information around which point should it rotate. 
PS. Sorry for little "mess" in this code, final version will be better. But if i cant proceed with even simple sketch how can i move forward :
 **XAML:**

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
      <Border>
        <Canvas Name="plotno" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" Width="856" Height="520">
          <Slider x:Name="slider1" Canvas.Left="631" Canvas.Top="100" Height="21" Width="198" ValueChanged="slider1_ValueChanged" TickPlacement="Both" SmallChange="1" Maximum="360"/>
        </Canvas>
      </Border>
    </Grid>
  </DockPanel>
```

**C#**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
      {
      public MainWindow()
      {
      InitializeComponent();
      }
      Line myLine = new Line();
      Line myLine2 = new Line();
      long centerheight;
      long centerwidth;
      private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {

      myLine.Stroke = Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
      centerwidth = Convert.ToInt64(plotno.Width / 2);
      centerheight = Convert.ToInt64(plotno.Height / 2);
      myLine.X1 = centerwidth;
      myLine.X2 = myLine.X1+100;
      myLine.Y1 = centerheight;
      myLine.Y2 = myLine.Y1 + 100;
      myLine.StrokeThickness = 10;
      plotno.Children.Add(myLine);
      //rotate by a degree
      myLine.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(myLine.X1, myLine.Y1);
      //RotateTransform r = new RotateTransform(0);
      //myLine.RenderTransform = r;
      //this should stick my second line to first one but first one disappears
      var newP1 = myLine.RenderTransform.Transform(new Point(myLine.X2, myLine.Y2));
      myLine2.X1 = newP1.X;
      myLine2.Y1 = newP1.Y;
      myLine2.X2 = myLine2.X1+100;
      myLine2.Y2 = myLine2.Y1 + 100;
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myLine.X1);
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myLine.Y1);
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myLine.X2);
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myLine.Y2);
      myLine2.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
      myLine2.StrokeThickness = 10;
      Line whereshouldbeminerotationpivot = new Line();
      whereshouldbeminerotationpivot.X1 = myLine.RenderTransformOrigin.X;
      whereshouldbeminerotationpivot.X2 = myLine.RenderTransformOrigin.X + 10;
      whereshouldbeminerotationpivot.Y1 = myLine.RenderTransformOrigin.Y;
      whereshouldbeminerotationpivot.Y2 = myLine.RenderTransformOrigin.Y + 10;
      whereshouldbeminerotationpivot.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
      whereshouldbeminerotationpivot.StrokeThickness = 20;

      plotno.Children.Add(whereshouldbeminerotationpivot);
      plotno.Children.Add(myLine2);

    }

    private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
      var linie = plotno.Children.OfType<Line>().ToList();
      foreach (var linia in linie)
      {
        plotno.Children.Remove(linia);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < plotno.Children.Capacity; i++)
      { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(plotno.Children.Count); }

      myLine.X1 = centerwidth;
      myLine.X2 = myLine.X1+100;
      myLine.Y1 = centerheight;
      myLine.Y2 = myLine.Y1 + 100;
myLine.Stroke = Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
      myLine.StrokeThickness = 10;
      plotno.Children.Add(myLine);
      //myLine.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(30,0.5,0.5);
      //rotate by a degree
      myLine.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(myLine.X1, myLine.Y1);
      RotateTransform r = new RotateTransform(e.NewValue);
      myLine.RenderTransform = r;
      //this should stick my second line to first one but first one disappears
      var newP1 = myLine.RenderTransform.Transform(new Point(myLine.X2, myLine.Y2));
      myLine2.X1 = newP1.X;
      myLine2.Y1 = newP1.Y;
      myLine2.X2 = newP1.X+100;
      myLine2.Y2 = newP1.Y+100;
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myLine.X1);
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myLine.Y1);
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myLine.X2);
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myLine.Y2);
      myLine2.Stroke = Brushes.Gray;
      myLine2.StrokeThickness = 10;
      Line whereshouldbeminerotationpivot=new Line();
      whereshouldbeminerotationpivot.X1 = myLine.RenderTransformOrigin.X;
      whereshouldbeminerotationpivot.X2 = myLine.RenderTransformOrigin.X+10;
      whereshouldbeminerotationpivot.Y1 = myLine.RenderTransformOrigin.Y;
      whereshouldbeminerotationpivot.Y2 = myLine.RenderTransformOrigin.Y+10;
whereshouldbeminerotationpivot.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
      whereshouldbeminerotationpivot.StrokeThickness = 20;

      plotno.Children.Add(whereshouldbeminerotationpivot);
      plotno.Children.Add(myLine2);
    }

  }
```

Comment: i've found what was wrong - Line 93
      RotateTransform r = new RotateTransform(e.NewValue, centerwidth,centerheight);

But still i don't know why my first line dissapears

Answer (score 0):

So as i mentioned earlier in a commento to my post - i just brainfarted and forgot that i have to actually use overloaded constructor for RotateTransform object. It looks like this:

```
Line 93 RotateTransform r = new RotateTransform(e.NewValue, centerwidth,centerheight);
```

BUT despite it rotates correctly (around one end of the line) line disappears when the second one overlaps with the first one. Anyone knows why? I tried changing order in which Childrens are added (visualised) but it doesn't work.
And i have a problem only with the first line. 
My marker in the middle of canvas and a second line is always visualised correctly